How to close an another window opened in PWA and get back to the main frame
When i open a new window (with window.open) i can't close it. I try window.close, history.back nothing happened.
Notice that the same code, running in the browser (Firefox) works perfectly.
I am using firefox to render the PWA on android tablet. In my case the usage of firefox is mandatory.
I want to close the opened tabs and go back to my main pwa screen
For example:
 handle() {
    if(this.mobileStore.isMobile && this.mobileStore.getOnline()){
      var tabs = window.open(useEnvStore().getUrl, '_blank')
      setTimeout(() => {
        tabs.close()
        window.location.reload()
      }, 1000)
    } else {
      window.location.reload()
    }
  }

I only want a new window and close it after few seconds. It's working on browser but not on PWA mode

Did you try another browser?

Yes same problem with Chrome

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I put the code above

To handle closing a window opened by window.open in a PWA, you can use Service Workers and inter-window messaging.
1. Update the Service Worker to listen for messages:
// In your service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data === 'close-tab') {
    self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
      clients.forEach(client => {
        client.postMessage('close-window');
      });
    });
  }
});

2. Modify the function that handles opening and closing the window:
function handle() {
  if(this.mobileStore.isMobile && this.mobileStore.getOnline()) {
    var tab = window.open(useEnvStore().getUrl, '_blank');

    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('close-tab');
        window.location.reload();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}

3. Add a message handler in the main window to close the tab:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.data === 'close-window') {
      window.close();
    }
  });
}

Explanation:

Service Worker: Listens for the close-tab message and sends a close-window message to all clients.
Main Window (handle function): Opens a new tab, sends the close-tab message to the Service Worker, and reloads the main window after 1 second.
Main Window Message Handler: In the main window (PWA), the message close-window is handled, triggering window.close().

This solution ensures that your PWA can close an opened tab by leveraging Service Worker messaging. Keep in mind that closing script-opened tabs may still be restricted on some devices and browsers.
